# How to pass a data in WkWebView URL in swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In my project I have a dictionary. I need to pass it to a WKWebView as a post parameter. When i try to convert String to URL it returns nil value. any advice to me?

This is my Dictionary named CartDict.

```
{
  "address_id" : "4064",
  "customer_id" : "3239",
  "language_id" : "1",
  "products" : [
    {
      "option" : "",
      "product_id" : "1576",
      "quantity" : "2"
    },
    {
      "option" : "",
      "product_id" : "1573",
      "quantity" : "1"
    },
    {
      "option" : "",
      "product_id" : "1575",
      "quantity" : "1"
    }
  ],
  "set_currency" : "EUR"
}
```

This is my code:

```
let urlStr = "https://test.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout_mobile&data=\(cartDict)"

let trimmedUrl = urlStr.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "")).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
let url = URL(string: trimmedUrl)
print(url)
self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set `httpBody` to your data from dictionary

```
let trimmedUrl = urlStr.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "")).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
let url = URL(string: trimmedUrl)! 
let dic:[String:Any] = ["address_id" : "4064", "customer_id" : "3239", "language_id" : "1", "products" : [ [ "option" : "", "product_id" : "1576", "quantity" : "2" ], [ "option" : "", "product_id" : "1573", "quantity" : "1" ], [ "option" : "", "product_id" : "1575", "quantity" : "1" ] ], "set_currency" : "EUR" ]
let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic)
var req = URLRequest(url: url)
req.httpBody =   data
self.webView.load(req)
```

Comment: so it seems dictionary cannot passed through url? only i can achieve this with httpbody request?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to make sure that the url string is valid, try printing it 
`print(urlStr)`
The post parameters are not url params usually, but http body parameters, thus need to be added to the body of the request. You need to know what format the server is expecting. Modern apis use JSON so you'd need to format your dictionary to json (however the dictionary you posted is actually not a swift dictionary, so it looks ok.).

```swift
    let urlStr = "https://test.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout_mobile"

    let trimmedUrl = urlStr.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "")).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
    let url = URL(string: trimmedUrl)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpBody = Data(cartDict.utf8)
    self.webView.load(request)
```

Comment: The url is not a valid one. I just replaced it with dummy example. My problem is i cannot post a dictionary in this url with the key "data". Is there any way to do this? or supposed i need to post it in httpbody?

Comment: the real question is what your server is expecting, this is not something you can decide on the front-end. If the backend is expecting a POST request with json body, it will not work with a url parameter. having a dictionary in the url would mean you'd have to url encode the entire dictionary and it would be very long like this `...&data=%7B%22address_id%22%3A%224064%22%2C%22customer_id%22%3A%223239%22%2C%22language_id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22products%22%3A%5B%7B%22option...`

Comment: My server expecting the URL like  "https://test.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout_mobile&data=\(dictionary)". This is working in android. But in iOS when i convert this String (urlStr) to URLRequest it returns nil.

Comment: I believe your url is also nil, otherwise your request would not be nil. This is why I suggested to print the `urlStr` to the console and try it in postman or similar rest client to verify that you are not making a mistake early on but trying to fix something else later in code. On Android you should print the url you're calling and compare it to iOS. Your particular area of interest should be the format of the dictionary after data=

Answer (score 0):

**From the comments**

---

> when i convert this String (urlStr) to URLRequest it returns nil

---

**If this is your question or it maybe useful for others in future.**

```
extension URL {
   public var queryParameters: [String: Any]? {
      guard let components = URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true), let queryItems = components.queryItems else { return nil }
      return queryItems.reduce(into: [String: String]()) { (result, item) in
          result[item.name] = item.value
      }
   }
}
```

In your WKNavigationDelegate methods on redirection

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
  guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
      decisionHandler(.allow)
      return
  }
  if url.absoluteString.lowercased().range(of: "redirection/url/you/expected/to/intercept") != nil {
      var parameters: [String: Any]?
      if let requestBody = navigationAction.request.httpBody {
          //If your data is JSON
          let requestJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: requestBody, options: [])
          if requestJSON = requestJSON as? [String: Any] {
              parameters = requestJSON
          }else {
              //If your data is utf8 encoded string
              let queryUrl = URL(string: url.absoluteString + "?" + String(decoding: requestBody, as: UTF8.self))
              parameters = queryUrl?.queryParameters
          }
      }
      //Your post payload in parameters
      //Handle it the way you want.
  }
  decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```